# Python cgi and stdin

Tags: python, cgi, stdin

I'm using pycurl to upload a file via put and python cgi script to receive the file on the server side. Essentially, the code on the server side is:

```
while True:
   next = sys.stdin.read(4096)
   if not next:
       break
   #.... write the buffer
```

This seems to work with text, but not binary files (I'm on windows).
With binary files, the loop doing stdin.read breaks after receiving anything around 10kb to 100kb. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run Python in binary mode.  Change your CGI script from:

```
#!C:/Python25/python.exe
```

or whatever it says to:

```
#!C:/Python25/python.exe -u
```

Or you can do it programmatically like this:

```
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

before starting to read from `stdin`.

Comment: Shouldn't that final slash be a period?

Comment: @unwind: Oops, well spotted.  Now fixed.

Comment: I'm curious.. why is this necessary?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Because on Windows, reading in text mode converts `\r\n` into `\n`, and will stop reading when it reads character 26 (EOF).  That's considered correct for a text file, but will corrupt a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead of cgi.  It will provide you an input file for the upload that's correctly opened.